# Como anexar uma DIV a outra DIV usando DOM

Tags: javascript

```
var X = createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(X);

var Y = createElement('div);
```

como anexo a div X a div Y?

Comment: Quando dizes "anexar" quere dizer colocar "ao lado de" ou "dentro de"?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de `document.body.appendChild(X);` (que anexa ao `body`), use:

```
Y.appendChild(X);
```